# Верстка блоков html

Tags: html, вёрстка, блок

Каким методом лучше сверстать блоки в макете чтобы было легче адаптировать под девайсы (bootstrap, Grid CSS и т.д.)? И каким образом расположить текст (абсолютом, внутри блоков и т.д.)? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может использовать фреймворк типа бутстрапа?

Comment: Не нужно текст сайта, то есть конктентную часть позиционировать абсолютом. Никогда. )) Абсолютом можно позиционировать небольшие элементы, которые служат дизайну - иконки там, кнопочки, рамки. А про позиционирование блоков, вам уже подсказали.